# Node js, how to run a code sync after a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

here is my code in which I try to update some documents of my database (MongoDB) 
using a for loop. however I want to run the next code after the loop is completed, 
as for example, I want to use some variables calculated inside the loop after it finished.
How can I do such using callback, promise, etc?

```
numPktUpdated = 0;
for (key in InvoicesPUT) { 
      Invoice.findOneAndUpdate({ InvoiceNumber: InvoicesPUT[key].InvoiceNumber }, InvoicesPUT[key]).exec()
      .then((doc) => {
           console.log("Update Succeeded")
           numPktUpdated = numPktUpdated + 1;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
            return resp.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": "error",
            "message": "DB Error while Updating: Wrong Packet"
            }));
            console.log(err);
     })
}
resp.send(numPktUpdated);
```

Here numPktUpdated = 0 is sent to client, although its real value after the loop is something else.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at `async.series` to perform an action after some promises have returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `Promise.all()`:

```
Promise.all(InvoicesPUT.map(InvoicePUT => {
    return Invoice.findOneAndUpdate({
        InvoiceNumber: InvoicePUT.InvoiceNumber
    }, InvoicePUT).exec()
    .then(doc => {
        console.log("Update Succeeded");
        numPktUpdated += 1;
    })
}))
.catch(err => {
    return resp.send(JSON.stringify({
        "status": "error",
        "message": "DB Error while Updating: Wrong Packet"
    }));
    console.log(err);
})
.then(() => {
    // What you want to do after the loop ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put code to the function, then run it with async

```
    async function  forLoopFunction(args){//here is a for loop
    }

    let ret = await forLoopFunction(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of Node v7.6, which brought support for the [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) pattern, you could use a simple [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function updateDocs() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        numPktUpdated = 0;
        for (key in InvoicesPUT) { 
              Invoice.findOneAndUpdate({ InvoiceNumber: InvoicesPUT[key].InvoiceNumber }, InvoicesPUT[key]).exec()
              .then((doc) => {
                   console.log("Update Succeeded")
                   numPktUpdated = numPktUpdated + 1;
                   resolve(numPktUpdated);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                    return resp.send(JSON.stringify({
                        "status": "error",
                        "message": "DB Error while Updating: Wrong Packet"
                    }));                    
             })
        }
    });
}


updateDocs().then(function(numPktUpdated) {
    resp.send(numPktUpdated);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // handle error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It worked with just a minor modification:

```
Promise.all(InvoicesPUT.map(invoice => {
                return Invoice.findOneAndUpdate({InvoiceNumber: invoice.InvoiceNumber}, invoice).exec()
                .then((doc) => {
                    console.log("Update Succeeded")
                    numPktUpdated = numPktUpdated + 1;
                })

            }))
            .catch((err) => {
                return resp.send(JSON.stringify({
                    "status": "error",
                    "message": "DB Error while Updating: Wrong Packet"
                }));
                console.log(err);
            })
            .then((resolve) => {
                return resp.send(JSON.stringify({
                    "status": "succed",
                    "LastSavedGUID": 654323,
                    "SyncDate": 1,
                    "pagenumber": numPktUpdated
                }));
            })
```